# A Windows application which uses Rhino JavaScript engine?

Tags: javascript, windows, rhino, javascript-engine

Is there a Windows application and a solution which is an IDE, and can execute the JavaScript sources, as if it is in Mozilla Firefox, meaning that it uses **Rhino JavaScript Engine**.

Except Mozilla Console, FireBug console, etc.

Comment: Does Eclipse RCP applications count? You can create use Rhino there...

Comment: well I am looking for an independent application and an IDE for primary use of JavaScript - only!

Comment: You can do that with Eclipse RCP I think... Eclipse RCP != Eclipse IDE...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some applications which use Rhino:

```
NAME                PURPOSE
Eclipse JSDT        JavaScript Developer Tools
HttpUnit            automated testing framework
HtmlUnit            browser for Java programs
JsDoc Toolkit       documentation tool
Pentaho BI Suite    business intelligence
PerStore Persistent JSON storage
```

[Komodo](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/komodoedit/info) uses the same JavaScript engine as Mozilla Firefox. It can execute JavaScript in the following ways:

- [JavaScript Macro API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905759/advanced-find-replace-text-expand-macros)
- [Code Intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113155/javascript-code-completition-done-right/4113205#4113205)
- [XUL Extensions](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/xul-preview-extension)
- [DOM Inspector](http://support.activestate.com/xpi/dom-inspector)

There are plugins for the [jQuery API](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/blob/master/src/codeintel/lib/codeintel2/catalogs/jquery.cix) along with a built-in [JavaScript API](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/8.0/komodo-js-api.html) which simplify things greatly.

There's also an IDE for Android which runs on Rhino:

- [Script It - JavaScript IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rbowman.scriptit&hl=en)

**References**

- [List of Mozilla-Based Applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/List_of_Mozilla-Based_Applications)
- [Rhino Source](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/rhino/)
- [HTTPUnit Source](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/httpunit/code/trunk/httpunit/)
- [HTMLUnit Source](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/htmlunit/code/trunk/htmlunit/)
- [PerStore Framework Source](https://github.com/kriszyp/perstore)
- [JSDoc Source](https://github.com/jiva-technology/jsdoc-toolkit)
- [JSDT Source](https://github.com/eclipse/vjet.jsdt.parser)

Comment: this is good, quite good... but how about an IDE in which you can integrate jQuery and just do the Non-DOM work in it... ? I belive that such software does not exist. Like an JavaScript-specific IDE!